# Module: ':app' platform 'android-32' not found even after installing Android API 32

Tags: android, gradle, intellij-idea

I am completely new to Android App Development and I'm trying to learn to develop apps through IntelliJ IDEA. When I try to open the activity_main.xml file, I get a prompt saying, "Design editor is unavailable until after a successful project sync", and when I try to sync, I get this error. This happens even after installing all Android versions (including 32) through Android SDK settings.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

[Here is the image of the error when trying to sync gradle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4e0CT.png)

Comment: Why aren’t you using Android Studio IDE for app development ?

Comment: I'm facing multiple errors using that too :(

Comment: You should use Android studio  only. and If still facing issues post here those issues

Answer (score 6):

The problem that Intellij IDEA doesn't have Android SDK configured. In particular - Android SDK 32. Even if you see that it is installed in the SDK Manager.
I don't remember when we started to see this issue. But it's easy to fix. It's is one time exercise for new installations only.

How to fix this:

1. Install Android SDK 32 (or any other required) in SDK Manager what you can find in IDEA preferences.
   [image]
2. Install JDK 11. Probably this is why IDEA has not configured Android SDKs automatically. The IDEA itself already runs on JDK 17 or higher.
3. Open your Android project (or just any project in IDEA), go to Project Settings -> SDKs. Press "+" menu button on top and select "Add Android SDK...". Select your *root* "android sdk" folder. Then choose SDK you needed.
   [image]
   [image]
   [image]
4. Press OK. Press "Sync Gradle Project" again.
5. Have Fun.

BTW, after years on Android apps development I would prefer Intellij IDEA over too buggy Android Studio. You on the right way ;)

Comment: lifesaver! It was the jdk 11 that fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

download and install jdk 11 version
and set it path to your project
and sync gradle!
that fixed it for me.
*(Make sure android api 32 in sdk manger is installed)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).